# Populating ListBox with a List(T) Class. Not using datasource

Tags: c#, listbox

I have the following list

```
static List<SectorBodies> MatchList = new List<SectorBodies>();
```

And it's associated class

```
public class SectorBodies
{
    public int MatchCount { get; set; }
    public string StringPosition { get; set; }

    public string SolarSystemFileComment { get; set; }
    public string SolarSystemX { get; set; }
    public string SolarSystemY { get; set; }
    public string SolarSystemZ { get; set; }

    public string OuterFileComment { get; set; }
    public string OuterOrbitX { get; set; }
    public string OuterOrbitY { get; set; }
    public string OuterOrbitZ { get; set; }
    public string OrbitName { get; set; }
    public string OrbitPrefab { get; set; }

    public string PlanetFileComment { get; set; }
    public string PlanetX { get; set; }
    public string PlanetY { get; set; }
    public string PlanetZ { get; set; }
    public string PlanetName { get; set; }
    public string PlanetBiome { get; set; }
    public string PlanetIsStart { get; set; }
}
```

The following is the watch list to give scope of whats inside
[image]

I am trying to populate a ListBox with a list element named as `OrbitName` without using the datasource bind as I would prefer to do manipulation of the results before populating. I am aware of `listBox1.Items.Add()` but i cant seem to populate it properly it just populates the listbox with the namespace.class in my case Parser.SectorBodies. So how do i using the Items.Add method add all the `OrbitName` into the ListBox

Comment: Use `listBox1.Items.Add()` but set `listBox1.DisplayMember=OrbitName`,for example. You must tell the ListBox what field should show

Comment: @Pikoh i actually had the DisplayMember but i assumed its use was tied to the datasource. Thanks that helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

`foreach(var item in MatchList) listbox1.Items.Add(item);
listbox1.DisplayMember="OrbitName";`

this will display the OrbitName for each item.

Comment: Great - please mark the answer as correct and others can know to use it too

Comment: I was waiting for the answer timer to run out. :)

Comment: :D thank you - and its funny how those timers can seem a long wait